# How to show consent form with UserMessagingPlatform?

Tags: java, android, gdprconsentform

I followed a [guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy) on Google's Documentation, to display a GDPR consent message and I can't get it to show, I used the code from the documentation, but edited the code from the [Privacy options](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy#privacy_options) section where I added the last argument like this:

```
consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
                this,
                params,
                (ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener) () -> {
                    UserMessagingPlatform.loadAndShowConsentFormIfRequired(
                            this,
                            (ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener) loadAndShowError -> {
                                // ...

                                // Consent has been gathered.

                                if (isPrivacyOptionsRequired()) {
                                    // Regenerate the options menu to include a privacy setting.
                                    ConsentVisibility = true;
                                }
                                else ConsentVisibility = false;
                            }
                    );
                }
        , (ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener) requestConsentError -> {
        // Consent gathering failed.
        Log.d("ConsentF", String.format("%s: %s",
                requestConsentError.getErrorCode(),
                requestConsentError.getMessage()));
    });
```

The things I've tried:

- Testing it with the options from the [Testing](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy#testing) section,
- Testing it without the testing options,
- Testing on an emulator and an actual device,
- I've also made sure, that my adblocker was inactive.

The consent doesn't show up no matter what I do.¸

**Edit:** Consent form was also added in Google's Console.

Comment: Are you trying to show consent in debug mode?

Comment: In debug mode, did you get "device-id" from logcat and place while calling for test CMP?

Comment: @SohaibAhmed I tried both, I gopt it from a log message like this: "Use new ConsentDebugSettings.Builder().addTestDeviceHashedId("x") to set this as a debug device." Where x was the device ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some odd reason my Consent Message got deleated, after readding it in the AdMob's Console, it didn't work with the debug settings, but it did with normal ones. So it works now.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way I test GDPR in my app:

```
            val consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(it)
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                consentInformation.reset()
            }

            val builder = ConsentRequestParameters
                .Builder()
                .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)

            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                val debugSettings = activity?.let {
                    ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(it)
                        .setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings.DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
                        .addTestDeviceHashedId("your_test_device_id")
                        .build()
                }
                builder.setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings)
            }

            val params = builder.build()

            consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate( ... )
```

consentInformation.reset() to reset if you accepted before.

setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings.DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA) to test device in EEA area

And make sure you created consent form follow document

Comment: It didn't even show up the first time for me. I've tried with reset, also double checked the test debug and params, and checked that  it was set to EEA, and it still didn't work. I have in Google's console.

Comment: consentInformation.reset()  use this api for resetting conset